# Заменить теги [c++] и [cli] на [с++-cli]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, замена-меток

Есть [~50 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20cli) с тегами [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) и [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli).
Эти теги надо заменить на [c++-cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli),
а тег [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli) сделать синонимом [command-line-interface](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line-interface) чтобы в дальнейшем юзеры не использовали его для C++/CLI

Comment: Раз уж тег `cli` неправильно используют, может быть, выкинуть его совсем? Если он останется как синоним command line interface, его будут ошибочно использовать в старом значении. А так вообще поддерживаю.

Comment: @VladD синонимы работают так, что ты пытаешься писать `cli`, а оно сразу же заменяется на `command-line-interface`

Comment: Даже так? Не знал. Тогда можно, почему бы и нет. Но может быть юзеры ассоциируют cli с чем-то другим, и будут ругаться на баг (ну то есть неинтуитивное поведение системы). В любом случае, не знаю как правильно. Если метка будет сразу разворачиваться в `command-line-interface`, может, они поймут, что что-то не так.

Comment: Кстати, у метки до сих пор нет описания. Неудивительно, что метку без описания использовали ошибочно.  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-cli/info

Answer (score 8):

Все вопросы заменил, осталось создать синоним(или вообще выпилить).